# DEM error when trying to do topographic correction in GRASS

Tags: raster, grass-gis, dem, srtm, aster

I'm new to GRASS gis and I'm trying to do a topographic correction (i.topo.corr) of 9 ASTER bands using SRTM dem. I keep getting this error message:

> ERROR: Illumination model is of CELL type

Is this error referring to my elevation raster, and if so how do I change the type to the appropriate one?

Answer (score 1):

"CELL" type means integer type (see also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_raster_semantics#Raster_map_precision_types). Since SRTM is delivered as integer map but i.topo.corr expects a floating point map, you need to convert/resample that map beforehand.

For resampling methods available in GRASS GIS, see the manual or Wiki, especially:

http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Interpolation#Resampling_of_raster_maps_to_finer_resolution

since you may want to match the resolution of your DEM to that of the ASTER channels.